# gnuplot giving warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

Tags: html, graph, gnuplot

I am using the gnuplot script

```
    #qe.conf
set terminal png truecolor
set output "qe.png"
set xrange ["400" : "700"]
set yrange ["0" : "1"]
set style data lines
plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
```

I am executing the gnuplot script qe.conf through a shell script
It gives me the following error

> > gnuplot> plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
> >                                            ^
> >              line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>
> gnuplot> plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title
>   "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
>                                                                     ^
>            line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>
> gnuplot> plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title
>   "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
>                                                                                                ^
>            line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points
>
> gnuplot> plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red", '' using 1:3 title
>   "%G-r", '' using 1:4 title "%G-b", '' using 1:5 title "%R"
>                                                                                                                           ^
>            line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

But when I execute qe.conf manually, I works fine

The datafile is here.

> 

```
400.0   0.3625060772
410.0   0.445987595886
420.0   0.503862994331
430.0   0.534251869841
440.0   0.576047041939
450.0   0.594211326218
460.0   0.58079588866
470.0   0.506666961836
480.0   0.495652452097
490.0   0.426107864611
500.0   0.342632041157
510.0   0.251232093174
520.0   0.178015786221
530.0   0.140803848655
540.0   0.120063881639
550.0   0.0995420648319
560.0   0.080193952073
570.0   0.0730989150532
580.0   0.0708069989426
590.0   0.0688014659014
600.0   0.0597099385221
610.0   0.0481330987744
620.0   0.042010859344
630.0   0.0425115579982
640.0   0.0460125024438
650.0   0.0515227545961
660.0   0.0559745367996
670.0   0.0629981328342
680.0   0.0573046109671
690.0   0.0688715871636
700.0   0.0742304568215
```

`

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Hi All, After hours of trying I still dont have the answer.
I tried the following things. I tried giving absolute paths for datafile, gnuscript and shell script. 
The command gnuplot qe.conf works fine if run from linux command prompt but when run through the shell script gives this error.

> line 10: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points

Request for help.

Comment: Check that the current working directory for gnuplot is the one you expect (insert `pwd` in the script to check this).

Comment: @Christoph The location of text file, configuration file and shell script are all the same

Comment: Please check this. And how do you call the shell script and the gnuplot configuration file? It must be something of this sort, since otherwise the script seems to work.

Comment: @Christoph: I have to read the data from an excel file and plot it. So I use python script to read the excel file and write to a text file qe.txt. Then the python script calls the shell script test.sh. The content of test.sh is 
#!/bin/bash
cat qe.conf | gnuplot

Comment: @Christoph: When I execute 
cat qe.conf | gnuplot
directly from the command prompt, it works fine

Comment: Ok, so please check the output of `pwd` when adding this to qe.conf and running the script! BTW: You can simply use `gnuplot qe.conf` although this shouldn't change anything.

Comment: @Christoph: I output of pwd gives the path to the current directory. The files qe.txt, qe.conf and test.sh all are present in the pwd. I also tried using gnuplot qe.conf. Again I am able to get it right by running it manually from command prompt.

Comment: @Christoph: any other suggestions??

Comment: Again, I tried looking for error similar to this but can't get to a solution. I tied using set datafile separator "\t". But no use. Help will be very much appreciated

Comment: @Christoph: Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: It is almost impossible to reproduce you problem since it seems to depend on some specific combination of settings on your system. The last thing: Put the line `print GPVAL_VERSION, GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL` in your gnuplot script. Maybe in the two cases two different gnuplot versions are picked, one of which may have a problem with something in your data file (Does that contain exclusively numbers?)

Comment: One remark: If the file is not found, you get `warning: Skipping unreadable file "MyFile"`. The message `warning: Skipping data file with no valid points` occurs e.g. when you try to use columns which do not exist in the file. So, I would have a look on the datafile. Is it really the same (`pwd`), and is its __content__ the same (editor)?
`

Comment: @sweber: Please see the datafile above in the question.

Comment: @sweber: Yes the datafile also exists in the same pwd

Comment: Ok, I see two colums, while you want to plot colums 2, 3, 4, 5 vs. 1.

Comment: @Christoph: Yes I got different numbers. GPVAL_VERSION gave 4.2 and GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL gave 4.

Comment: @Sweber: For simpliciity I am just trying to plot 1 with 2. 
plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red"
Is it correct?

Comment: @sweber: My script

#qe.conf
reset
print GPVAL_VERSION
print GPVAL_PATCHLEVEL
set terminal png truecolor
set output "qe.png"
set xrange ["400" : "700"]
set yrange ["0" : "0.9"]
set style data lines
plot "qe.txt" using 1:2 title "%Red"

Comment: @mayday_ranger: I saw a post from you when you had the similar issue. Could you please suggest something?

Answer (score 14):

I get this error everytime I try to plot a `.csv` (comma separated variables) file, I forget that sometimes gnuplot needs to be reminded what the delimiter is. Usually I get the same error you mention, sometimes I get no error, but in either case, no data is plotted until delimiter is defined properly.

gnuplot defaults to whitespace as a delimiter, but perhaps you overrode that and set it to comma or something. Try telling gnuplot what your delimiter is.

`set datafile separator " "`

or

`set datafile separator whitespace`

and then of course for comma try `","` and tab would try `"\t"`

I find it best to keep putting the `set datafile separator " "` into the top of my scripts, to remind myself.

Comment: I was having the same problem and this fixed my error.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try checking the **encoding** on you data file.

I've just come across this exact problem as well when trying to plot a data file. And it turned out that Gnuplot was unable to understand the data file due to its encoding (which was UTF-16LE).

When I changed the file's encoding to **UTF-8**, Gnuplot was able to read it without issues.

Since this post is already a bit old, you've probably already managed to solve it. Though I just thought it might help anyone else who also gets this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you're trying to plot the 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns of a two column dataset.  If you change your plot command to drop everything that's using 1:3 or higher, it should work just fine.  The error message is telling you that the data file really is empty (in the higher columns).

Comment: According to the comments (second last one), the script also fails when plotting only using 1:2

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I had the same issue using Gnuplot 5.0.4. As Aendur suggested, the encoding could be problematic. What fixed it for me was, using TextWrangler, to change the **line breaks**, in my case from "Mac Classic (CR)", to "**Unix (LF)**" without having to change the encoding of the file to UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar issues while working on a `C` project. It turned out I didn't properly close my data files and it prevented `gnuplot` from reading it. Here is how you should close your files:

```
if (fclose(data) == 0){ // always close file for gnuplot
    return 1;
}else{
    printf("Erreur: Le programme a rencontré une erreur en essayant de fermer le fichier");
    return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps!